# Galleria and Infinite carousel and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, galleria, infinite, infinite-carousel

I am using Galleria plugin for a image gallery on a page this page is loaded in a frame page using ajax this is the ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
function loadTab(pageUrl) 
{ 
    $.ajax( 
    { 
        url: pageUrl, 
        cache: true, 
        success: function(load) 
        { 
            $("#tabcontent").empty().append(load); 
        } 
    }); 
} 
 
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    
    $("#tab1").ready(function() 
    { 
        loadTab("acasa.html"); 
    }); 
    
    $("#tab1").click(function() 
    { 
        loadTab("acasa.html"); 
    }); 
 
    $("#tab2").click(function() 
    { 
        loadTab("desprenoi.html"); 
    }); 
 
    $("#tab3").click(function() 
    { 
        loadTab("servici.html"); 
    }); 
 
    $("#tab4").click(function() 
    { 
        loadTab("parteneri.html"); 
    });
    
    $("#tab5").click(function() 
    { 
        loadTab("galerie.html"); 
    }); 
    
    $("#tab6").click(function() 
    { 
        loadTab("contact.php"); 
    }); 



});
});
```

On the frame page I`m using Infinite gallery that uses <ul></ul> tags my problem is that offline, testing the page it work`s perfect but on the server(online) the gallery using galleria goes to the dogs. What I mean is that I have in stead of the gallery the a list of all the images.

P.S. Can enyone help me find a better ajax script :D

You can find the online wersion here[link text][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I an a Idiot because there was no problem but I have positioned rong the script`s

Am I a nube? Yes I am.